# Zookeeper in-memory log

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, in-memory

Does ZooKeeper have an "in-memory log"? I've some experience with ZooKeeper but I never seen anything like it before (from the client side), and after searching I haven't found anything related to an in-memory log. As far as I know, every operation (create, setData, delete) is made on disk.

However, in the paper [Ravana: Controller Fault-Tolerance in Software-Defined Networking](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~jrex/papers/ravana15.pdf) the authors

> Event logging: The master saves each event in ZooKeeper’s distributed
>   in-memory log. Slaves monitor the log by registering a
>   trigger for it. When a new event is propagated to a slave’s log, the
>   trigger is activated so that the slave can read the newly arrived event
>   locally.

So, assuming that there is an in-memory log, how would a (java) client app use it? Or is it server side only?